# Removing "Edit" link in Leads Detail View for Converted Leads in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

How can i remove "Edit" link in "Leads Detail View" for Converted Leads in SugarCRM.
I want to have "Edit" link to be visible for only Non-Converted leads.

Regards,
Vishal Sharma

Answer (score 1):

in the Leads Detail View you have an hidden field:

```
 `<input type="hidden" class="sugar_field" id="status" value="Converted"/>`
```

just include an js in the detailviewdefs.php where you check for that field and if value is "Converted" hide the Edit Button.

```
SUGAR.util.doWhen("typeof $ != 'undefined'", function(){
    if($('#status').val() == "Converted"){
        $("#edit_button").hide();
    }
});
```